# Saving Data from iphone app to text file in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to save my application data in text file in documents folder 
I am using following way to store but it store single string i want that my data is in array how may store all the contents of array in text files

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString*yourString=@"This is working fine";
  NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
  NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
  [stringWithoutSpaces writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

My Array is like Following

```
    DataController *coffeeObj = [appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];




 cell.resturantLocationLabel.text=coffeeObj.resturantLocation;
     cell.foodQualityRatingLabel.text=coffeeObj.foodQualityRating;
     cell.foodPresentationRatingLabel.text=coffeeObj.foodPresentationRating;
     cell.waiterRatingLabel.text=coffeeObj.waiterRating;
     cell.ambienceRatingLabel.text=coffeeObj.ambienceRating;
     cell.overallRatingLabel.text=coffeeObj.overallRating;
     cell.commentsLabel.text=coffeeObj.comments;
     cell.emailAddressLabel.text=coffeeObj.emailAddress;
     cell.addtoMailingListLabel.text=coffeeObj.addtoMailingList;


     NSString*test=coffeeObj.comments;
```

Comment: And what is your data in array ? Can we have sample please ?

Answer (score 0):

add your complete array data in NSMutableString and then store in text file.

Comment: can you tell me how to add array into NSMutableString

Comment: NSMutaleString *_Str = = [[NSMutableString alloc]init]; for(int i = 0;i < array.count ;i++) { [Str stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:i]]; }

Comment: see my update code i have array of objects how may i use this like your given i want all the contents

Comment: NSMutaleString *_Str = = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

for(int i = 0;i < array.count ;i++)
{
DataController *coffeeObj = [appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[Str stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",coffeeObj.resturantLocation];
[Str stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", coffeeObj.foodQualityRating];
[Str stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", coffeeObj.foodPresentationRating];
..
…
…..
……
[Str stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", coffeeObj.comments];
}

Answer (score 0):

```
// Here you set your text.    
NSString *yourAppendingText = @"yourAppendingText";  

// Here you get access to the file in Documents directory of your application bundle.
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentFile = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];

// Here you read current existing text from that file
NSString *textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:documentFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

// Here you append new text to the existing one if it is
if(textFromFile){
    NSLog(@"appending");
    NSString *textToFile = [textFromFile stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",yourAppendingText]];
    // Here you save the updated text to that file
    [textToFile writeToFile:documentFile atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

}
else{

    NSLog(@"not appending");
    [yourAppendingText writeToFile:documentFile atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
}
```